# How to use dark mode in iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, ios-darkmode

While I am developing the iOS app I need to test it in simulator with dark mode option so I can get more clarity about the app UI. But when I go to the Setting I am not getting option for dark mode as real device showing.

Answer (score 791, accepted):

In **Settings**, scroll down to **Developer** and then **Dark Appearance**…

[image]

---

*Update*

In addition to the above, there are now *many* other ways to enable dark appearance in the simulator, as shown in the many great answers below.

• Change Environment Overrides from Xcode ([@AshCameron](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57990220/123632))

• Toggle Appearance <kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> from the Simulator menu ([@Shredder2794](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61035187/123632))

• Update from the command line using `xcrun simctl ui booted appearance …` ([@blackjacx, @tadija](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62191811/123632))

• Programmatically using `overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark` ([@thisIsTheFoxe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57990969/123632))

• Specify `UIUserInterfaceStyle` in your *info.plist* (@[DhavalGevariya](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61608775/123632))

• Use SimGenie from Curtis Herbert…  https://simgenie.app

Answer (score 117):

You can toggle the interface mode (i.e. Light / Dark) as well as adjust dynamic type setting on the fly (when the simulator is running) like this:

[image: Dark mode with Xcode]

Comment: Great answer. Also good to see all the other size and accessibility things, makes it so much quicker when developing

Comment: Nice  I would have never clicked on that unmarked button.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer I think, short and handy instead of going through multiple menus.

Comment: Protip: if you have Simulator in the foreground, over Xcode, you can Command+click on that button in Xcode (and on any switches in that panel) to change settings while keeping the simulator in front! credit: WWDC state of the union iirc

Comment: Note that this will only work if you are actively running the app from Xcode—as soon as you've stopped the session, you cannot use this method. However, in practice I find that I often still want to open some app that I know I have installed on the Simulator …and switch to light/dark. For that, **⇧ ⌘ A** still works best!

Answer (score 90):

You can use the "Toggle Appearance" (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>) setting from the Simulator menu:

> Simulator > Features > Toggle Appearance <kbd>⇧⌘A</kbd>

[image: Toggle Appearance]

Comment: Thnx, it helped a lot.

Comment: By far the easiest option

Comment: seems : Toggle Appearance ⇧⌘A from the Simulator menu is COMPLETELY broken in both Xcode 13 (June 2022) AND new Xcode 14

Comment: In 2024 this is the best answer :)

Comment: Still completely broken in Xcode 15.3, does not toggle appearance

Answer (score 18):

## Automated Appearance Change

### Xcode 11.4

Apple released a powerful Xcode update which contains some useful things for this topic. Appearance can now be selected directly in the simulator. Just select `Features > Toggle Appearance` or <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>. The automatic appearance switching could stil be important, e.g. for automated screenshot tests on the command line. The script becomes easy like this when using Xcode 11.4:

```sh
device_ids=("C741F3CD-FDAC-49EA-A4DB-7F797B97291E" "428183B6-3EB8-4D36-9938-9D07C141BF49")

# The value to use is now just 'dark' or 'light'
appearance=dark

for device in "${device_ids[@]}"; do
  xcrun simctl boot $device
  xcrun simctl ui $device appearance $appearance
done
```

No more simulator killing or re-setting needed which is a huge performance win. Also no fiddling around with any plist tools anymore - ever. keep in mind that you have to use device ids that are available in the runtime you use. Find them out using `xcrun simctl list`.

See also my complete script: https://github.com/Blackjacx/Scripts/blob/master/set-simulator-style.sh

### Xcode 11.3

There is a way using the command line to switch a simulator between light and dark mode. If you have an array with your device IDs you can do the following:

```sh
device_ids=("C741F3CD-FDAC-49EA-A4DB-7F797B97291E" "428183B6-3EB8-4D36-9938-9D07C141BF49")

# Determine the plist value for the desired style: "dark" -> 2 / "light" -> 1
style=2

for device_id in "${device_ids[@]}"; do
  plist_path="${HOME}/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/${device_id}/data/Library/Preferences/com.apple.uikitservices.userInterfaceStyleMode.plist"  
  printf '\n%s' "Set style $style for device $device_id ($plist_path)"

  killall "Simulator"
  xcrun simctl shutdown booted
  xcrun simctl erase $device_id

  # Crate the plist since it might not be available after erase
  [[ ! -f "$plist_path" ]] && /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "save" $plist_path  
  # Set the style mode
  plutil -replace UserInterfaceStyleMode -integer $style $plist_path
done
```

If you want to specify device names in your script - since device IDs are different on different machines - you can also easily find the id's of them using the following bash code:

```sh
device_names=("iPhone SE" "iPhone 8" "iPhone 11 Pro" "iPhone 11 Pro Max")
device_ids=()

for name in "${device_names[@]}"; do
  id=$(xcrun simctl list --json | jq ".devices | .[] | .[] | select(.name == \"$name\") | .udid" | cut -d\" -f2)
  device_ids+=("$id")
done

printf '%s\n' "${device_ids[@]}"
```

Comment: As of Xcode 11.4 this is supported directly by Simulator.app and the `xcrun simctl ui` command.

Comment: Yep saw this - I'll update the answer as soon as I tested everything  The automation is still nice - especially for automated tests. The new simctl setting will make the above code much easier.

Answer (score 12):

Alternatively, you can also switch the appearance programmatically ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting_dark_mode_in_your_interface/choosing_a_specific_interface_style_for_your_ios_app)):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    #if DEBUG
    // change the appearance only while testing  
    overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
    #endif
}
```

Answer (score 12):

from terminal:

```
xcrun simctl ui booted appearance light

xcrun simctl ui booted appearance dark
```

Comment: Code only answers are allowed, but it's encouraged to explain the answer as well. Consider adding some explanation.

Answer (score 6):

There are two ways to enable dark mode in Simulator.
Note: Make sure that you’re using iOS 13 simulator. X-D

**Solution 1:** *Change build settings*

1. Open *Settings* app
2. Select *Developer*
3. Enable *Dark appearance*

[image: Screenshot-1]

**Solution 2:** *Programmatically*

Simply add this code block in your ViewController file.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    #if DEBUG
    // This changes appearance only for debug mode
    overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .dark
    #endif
}
```

[image: Screenshot-2]

Check this [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting_dark_mode_in_your_interface/choosing_a_specific_interface_style_for_your_ios_app?fireglass_rsn=true) for more details.

Comment: Fantastic answer. Helped immensely. Toggle appearance from the simulator menu isn't working for me in some cases but from settings does!

Answer (score -1):

you can use keyboard shortcut shift + command + A to toggle appearance of simulator.

Comment: Please do not post duplicate answers.