# How to enable Dark Mode on the Simulator?

Tags: xcode

I’m trying to figure out how to turn on the new dark mode on the Xcode simulator. As far as I know it turns on by itself on real devices when it’s dark. 
Is there a way to trigger this on the simulator?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use dark mode in simulator iOS 13?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57988687/how-to-use-dark-mode-in-simulator-ios-13)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

There are two ways to activate the dark mode in Xcode 11. Both require you manual steps and are not automatic depending on the time.

**1. Environment Overrides**

The preferred one is to use the Environment Overrides inside Xcode. When running the App on the simulator in Xcode appears a button in the debugger controls next to 'Debug Memory Graph' and 'Simulate Location'. There you will find a menu for enabling dark mode, as well as choose text size and other accessibility settings.

[image: Dark Mode Settings in Xcode11]

**2. Simulator Settings**

Alternatively you can go inside the Settings App on the simulator:

> Settings > Developer > Dark Appearance

Comment: Environment Overrides seems to be the best way. Then you can keep your app in the foreground. Unless you run the Settings app and your app side-by-side.

Comment: Not suitable for debug dark mode on launch screen

Answer (score 24):

Here I got it. Open **Setting -> Developer -> Dark Appearance**

[image]

Comment: Isn't this exactly what [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58197506/1364007) said?

Answer (score 15):

On the Simulator>Features>Toggle Appearances changed the state for me:[image]

there is also the Shift+Command+A option that also works.

Comment: In iOS 16 Beta 1 there is no option to change dark/light mode here.

Answer (score 1):

It’s also possible to activate dark mode on your iOS simulator by using the following command:

```
xcrun simctl ui booted appearance dark
```

To change to light mode, run this:

```
xcrun simctl ui booted appearance light
```