# How to use dark mode in simulator iOS 12.4?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I need to test my app on simulator with dark mode option, but when I go to the Setting I am not getting option for dark mode as real device showing.

I tried this : [How to use dark mode in simulator iOS 13?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57988687/how-to-use-dark-mode-in-simulator-ios-13), but there is no option for "Dark Appearance". Can someone help me.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Dark mode](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/dark-mode/) is available in iOS 13.0 and later